# process env file not working for firebase config file?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, dotenv

So I have my firebase.config.js file and I want to hide the API_KEY and the other variables using env for some reason I keep getting the error that the process is not defined within the config file. I cannot seem to figure out why this is the case I have followed the REACT_APP part as well for the env files but it seems to be that process is the issue, the env file is defined in the root of my project the same level as the package json files. I put dummy values in for the env file to hide the info also. I have attached an image of my file structure for the .env file

Exact error message I get when I start my app:

> firebase.config.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
> at firebase.config.js:11:11

File Structure image:

[image: file structure]

env file:

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY="tester"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN="test"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID="tester"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET="test"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID="123"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID="123test"
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID="tester"
```

firebase.config.js, this file is within the src folder and another level down config folder

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// import firebase from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

Comment: Note: it looks like this is JavaScript code that is sent to the user's browser to run there. In that case putting the Firebase configuration in `env` won't make any difference, as the values are going to be used on the client anyway. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public on why this is not only working-as-intended, but actually required - and how to secure data access instead.

Comment: If you want to use Firebase web client libraries in your app, it's impossible to fully hide all those values.  They need to end up in the client app somehow in order to initialize the SDK.  This is unavoidable and by design as Frank said.  The best you can do is make it hard (but not impossible) for someone to get a hold of the values.  Instead, you should make sure you're using proper user authentication and security rules or some other backend mechanism to control access to data.